# PHP-PDO error: An invalid keyword 'host' was specified in the DSN string

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

Trying to connect to mssql server on smarterasp.net dns but without success so far. Had a prior issue with the drivers. Installed them and they are working perfectly (added them in php.ini)

Using **php version:5.6**, added to php.ini the following in order for the *php-pdo-mssql* to work:

- extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
- extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
- extension=php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
- extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll

What have I done so far on this code:

```
<?php
 try {
     $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:host=host_name_string;dbname=database_name_string", "username_string", "password_string");

     // set the PDO error mode to exception
     $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     echo "Connected successfully"; 
 }
 catch(PDOException $e)
 {
     echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
 }

?>
```

- instead of dbname I have put database, it doesn't work
- instead of dbname I have put Database, it doesn't work
- I have added the port 1433 after the host name example:

> "sqlsrv:host=host_name_string,1433;Database=database_name_string"

it doesn't work

- I have added the port 1433 after the host name example in this way

> "sqlsrv:host=host_name_string;port=1433;Database=database_name_string"

it doesn't work

I have tested the connection with my SQL sever management studio and the given data (values that I'm using here as parameters are 100% fine)

What are my other options?

Comment: try this format `$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=localhost;Database=testdb", "UserName", "Password");`

Comment: I' ve tried but this says the following: This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server to communicate with SQL Server and to be honest I don't think I should install additional things... Or maybe I  should?

Comment: i don't think you have any other option -- but have never worked with a MS server before

Comment: I think you are right I ll do that if it works then post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the correct format for the connection is:

```
$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=localhost;Database=testdb", "UserName", "Password");
```

from the manual page: [PDO_SQLSRV DSN](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.connection.php)

Comment: Thanks for this non-obvious syntax.  I was using `$conn = new PDO ("dblib:host=$srv_host:$srv_port;dbname=$srv_dbname", "$srv_username", "$srv_password");` for the same connection on my linux server, and wouldn't have thought I needed to change *this*, since I thought it was abstracted by PDO.